# SharePoint search between alphabetic range

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, search-engine

Hypothetical Project; I have an entire dictionary scanned page by page and stored in PDF format on SharePoint. Each Page is one pdf file.

Each PDF contains keywords which include the dictionary order tags which tell us what words are listed on the page. For example ABE-GRE will include words like 'brag' because in alphabetic order it lies between ABE and GRE.

How can I get SharePoint search to return the ABE-GRE page when I search for 'brag'?